# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (0,) - sm.OLS.from

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy realizando lo siguiente para un curso de regresion lineal, tengo un conjunto de datos de NHANES y lo estoy realizando por COURSERA, es la segunda vez que ejecuto sm.OLS y no estoy familiarizado como funciona. De antemano, la primera vez que lo hice funciono bien, pero estoy modificando una variable de interes y ahora esta generando error, el primer codigo que ejecute y funciono correctamente fue:

```
model = sm.OLS.from_formula("BPXSY1 ~ RIDAGEYR + GENERO + BMXBMI ", data=datos)
resultado = model.fit()
resultado.summary()


from statsmodels.sandbox.predict_functional import predict_functional


values = {"GENERO": "Femenino", "RIAGENDR": 1, "BMXBMI": 25,
          "DMDEDUC2": 1, "RIDRETH1": 1, "SMQ020": 1}

# Los valores devueltos son los valores pronosticados (pr), las bandas de confianza (cb),
# y los valores de la función (fv).
pr, cb, fv = predict_functional(resultado, "RIDAGEYR",
                values=values, ci_method="simultaneous")

ax = sns.lineplot(fv, pr, lw=4)
ax.fill_between(fv, cb[:, 0], cb[:, 1], color='grey', alpha=0.4)
ax.set_xlabel("Age")
_ = ax.set_ylabel("SBP")
```

Eso se ejecuta correctamente y me gráfica la regresión lineal. No obstante en el ejercicio  debo modificar el diccionario values y eliminar BMXBMI y definir en RIDAGEYR 50 años, para que nuevamente modifique la gráfica con otros valores para hacer predicciones sobre un sujeto especifico. El ideal es hacer esto y entiendo que el diccionario son valores fijos para facilitar el tema predictivo en la regresion.

```
values_1 = {"GENERO": "Femenino", "RIAGENDR": 1, "RIDAGEYR":50,        
            "DMDEDUC2": 1, "RIDRETH1": 1, "SMQ020": 1}

pr, cb, fv = predict_functional(resultado, "BMXBMI",
                values={"RIDAGEYR":50,"GENERO": "Femenino"}, ci_method="simultaneous")

ax = sns.lineplot(fv, pr, lw=4)
ax.fill_between(fv, cb[:, 0], cb[:, 1], color='grey', alpha=0.4)
ax.set_xlabel("BMI")
_ = ax.set_ylabel("SBP")
```

Pero luego de hacer eso salta el error, pero no entiendo por qué, según lo que entiendo el tamaño del array no es el mismo y por eso hay error.

````
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_13177/4140277002.py in <module>
      1 #values_1 = {"GENERO": "Femenino", "RIAGENDR": 1, "RIDAGEYR":50,          "DMDEDUC2": 1, "RIDRETH1": 1, "SMQ020": 1}
      2 
----> 3 pr, cb, fv = predict_functional(resultado, "BMXBMI",
      4                 values={"RIDAGEYR":50,"GENERO": "Femenino"}, ci_method="simultaneous")
      5 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/sandbox/predict_functional.py in predict_functional(result, focus_var, summaries, values, summaries2, values2, alpha, ci_method, linear, num_points, exog, exog2, **kwargs)
    369         sigma, c = _glm_basic_scr(result, dexog, alpha)
    370         cb = np.zeros((dexog.shape[0], 2))
--> 371         cb[:, 0] = pred - c*sigma
    372         cb[:, 1] = pred + c*sigma
    373 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in new_method(self, other)
     68         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     69 
---> 70         return method(self, other)
     71 
     72     return new_method

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py in __sub__(self, other)
    106     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__sub__")
    107     def __sub__(self, other):
--> 108         return self._arith_method(other, operator.sub)
    109 
    110     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__rsub__")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _arith_method(self, other, op)
   5637     def _arith_method(self, other, op):
   5638         self, other = ops.align_method_SERIES(self, other)
-> 5639         return base.IndexOpsMixin._arith_method(self, other, op)
   5640 
   5641 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _arith_method(self, other, op)
   1293 
   1294         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 1295             result = ops.arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
   1296 
   1297         return self._construct_result(result, name=res_name)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in arithmetic_op(left, right, op)
    220         _bool_arith_check(op, left, right)
    221 
--> 222         res_values = _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op)
    223 
    224     return res_values

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
    161 
    162     try:
--> 163         result = func(left, right)
    164     except TypeError:
    165         if not is_cmp and (is_object_dtype(left.dtype) or is_object_dtype(right)):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in evaluate(op, a, b, use_numexpr)
    237         if use_numexpr:
    238             # error: "None" not callable
--> 239             return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore[misc]
    240     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    241 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b)
    126 
    127     if result is None:
--> 128         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    129 
    130     return result

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
     67     if _TEST_MODE:
     68         _store_test_result(False)
---> 69     return op(a, b)
     70 
     71 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (0,) ```

Pero no entiendo por qué sucede esto, es la primera vez que se genera este error, e intentado mirar la documentación y sé que lo que pasa es que se esta generando en fv una salida de nans, pero no entiendo por qué si BMXBMI existe y es cuantitativa. 

Si me pueden ayudar estaría agradecido, es la segunda vez que uso la formula pero no sé que sucede. 

Finalmente, mi dataframe se llama datos. Su tamaño es asi (5735, 29) no entiendo por qué da el error y sobre todo, como puedo solucionarlo.
````